# Problem with empty header names in numpy genfromtxt

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, csv

I have a csv file with an empty column name, like this:

```
,colname1,colname2
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

If I use `np.genfromtxt` to get the two named columns, it's fine:

```
>>> print(np.genfromtxt("myfile.csv", delimiter=",", usecols=(1, 2), names=True))
array([(2., 3.), (5., 6.)],
      dtype=[('colname1', '<f8'), ('colname2', '<f8')])
```

But if I just ask for the first named column, the correct values are returned, but the column itself is labelled "column2":

```
>>> print(np.genfromtxt("myfile.csv", delimiter=",", usecols=(1), names=True))
array([(2.,), (5.,)], dtype=[('colname2', '<f8')])
```

numpy version '1.20.0', OS X, Python 3.7. Is this a bug?

Comment: Your 2 commands are the same!

Comment: Oops, sorry. Edited

Comment: You are welcome to explore the `genfromtxt` code.  I don't see any provisions in the docs for dealing with missing header fields.  You may have to provide your own names.

Comment: It's not so much that they are missing, just that they are empty, I guess. Either way, it's the inconsistent behaviour that caught me out (i.e. it works when all the non-empty columns are specified, but returns the wrong names (with no error message) when only some are.